# why my open rate of my firebase push notification single item always shows zero count?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]

as you can see from image above, all push notification always shows zero open rate, even though I am pretty sure that at least 1% will open the push notification.

I want to track the open rate per sent message in a day.

but if open the overall report based on the day from the firebase console, it will track the open rate of all messages sent in a day like the image below:

[image]

so why the open rate per sent message like in the first picture always show zero ?

in Android I use this gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
 implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

my messaging service class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    //*********** Called when the Notification is Received ********//


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Bitmap notificationBitmap = null;
        String notification_title, notification_message, notification_image = "";


        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            notification_title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            notification_message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
            notification_image = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
        } else {
            notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }


        notificationBitmap = getBitmapFromUrl(notification_image);


        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        NotificationHelper.showNewNotification
                (
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        notificationIntent,
                        notification_title,
                        notification_message,
                        notificationBitmap
                );

    }


    public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(imageUrl)) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

what went wrong here ?

Comment: there are nothing wrong when you send your notification from firebase panel . It shows 0%. Same as with me.

Comment: @BlackBlind thank you. but the problem is, I want to know how much the open rate for each message I sent to the user. and I can't get that data.

Comment: I send push notifications using postman. In my case also, open count is 0. but i personally know the notification was opened by people

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and it was caused by the missing Firebase Analytics library.

Documentation [for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

> Step 4: Add Firebase SDKs to your app
> ...
> // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

Documentation [for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup):

> Step 4: Add Firebase SDKs to your app
> ...
> 4. Choose the Firebase libraries you want to use.
> If Google Analytics is enabled in your Firebase project, make sure to add
> FirebaseAnalytics. For Analytics without IDFA collection capability, add
> FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdId instead.

Google Analytics also has a setup guide in the Admin UI (Admin - Property - Data Streams, select the stream, click "SDK Setup Instructions"):

[image: Google Analytics - SDK Setup Instructions]