# Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications showing 0 opens and 0 clicks

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

Notifications seem to be sending fine with expected delivery quantities, but opens and clicks are both 0 for multiple different messages sent (both recurring and one-off) through the Firebase Cloud Messaging tool. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570054/why-my-open-rate-of-my-firebase-push-notification-single-item-always-shows-zero/74238674#74238674, I posted a possible solution in that thread, in our case the Firebase Analytics library was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try export data to Big Query and check there? [image]