# Firebase cloud messaging push notification shows 0% open and 0 clicks

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image: Hello!]

Notifications seem to be sending fine with expected delivery quantities, but opens and clicks are both 0 for multiple different messages sent
I want to track the open rate per sent message in a day.

but if open the overall report based on the day from the firebase console, it will track the open rate of all messages sent in a day like an image below: so why the open rate per sent message like in the first picture always show zero ?

[image]

Comment: Can't tell from the limited data you've shared. Impossible to tell if the overall numbers apply to a different report than you showed, maybe iOS vs Android, a different date range, or some filter that is set on the first charts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570054/why-my-open-rate-of-my-firebase-push-notification-single-item-always-shows-zero/74238674#74238674, I posted a possible solution in that thread, in our case the Firebase Analytics library was missing.